# How to Get syntax highlight of LaTeX in Debian's Vim?

Tags: filetype-tex, linux-debian

I get no syntax highlight now in Debian's Vim by the workflow which works in Ubuntu 16.04: installation of packages and activating syntax

1. installation `apt-get install vim texlive-full`
2. activation in Vim, `:set syntax=latex`

I know that the Texlive is working because I get correct LaTeX syntax in Geany.

Debian: 8.5
Vim: release of the year 2006

Comment: Vim version can be found out with `:ver` (post only 7.x.xxxx). Please mention if you have a personal vimrc. You need `syntax on`. The filetype for latex is `tex`, not `latex`. For tex it is `plaintex`. The sentence `I know that the Texlive is working because I get correct LaTeX syntax in Geany.` is not true: syntax highlighting in editors (geany, vim, ...) works without having texlive installed at all and is no indication whether texlive actually works.

Answer (score 3):

And to make it persistent, check out vim's help files under the keyword `au` for autocmd

```
:h au
```

Then create a group (i.e. *scope/namespace* as the ubiquitous term) to protect yourself from duplicate definitions (just like an include guard in C)

```
augroup debianlatexfix 
  " Remove all vimrc autocommands within scope
  autocmd! 
  autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.tex   set syntax=tex
  autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.cls   set syntax=tex
augroup END
```

Comment: That is default on debian. Have a look at $VIMRUNTIME/filetype.vim

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Cool beans. Prob should tell that to the questioner though.

Answer (score 1):

There is no latex.vim syntax file that ships with Vim (as far as I know, and see on this Fedora 21 install).

Try `:set syntax=context` or `tex` or `plaintex` or `initex`

I find `context` a favourite, but that may be first exposure syndrome and the choice of colours.

Comment: Nothing of those work.

Comment: Take a look in `/usr/share/vim/vimNN/syntax/` (the NN will be a version spec, likely 70 if your Vim is from 2006), it's vim74 here.  See if there are any `*tex*` files.  Make sure `:syntax on` is on, and check to see if `:version` shows `+syntax`.  (You may need to install a variant Vim package).  And there are choices there, vim-gnome, vim-gtk, vim-nox etc.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line in `$HOME/.vimrc`

```
syntax on
```

Output: syntax highlight works and their changes too, etc with `:set syntax=latex`.